# Sencha Architect 4.2 - Framework Error Converting circular structures to JSON

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, extjs7

Following the tutorial here, https://docs.sencha.com/architect/4.2/guides/tutorials/first_desktop_application.html

And after configuring the Model, Store and Ajax Proxy, I'm getting a "Framework Error: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" error when I click on "Load Data". Is there a solutions/workaround for this? Search on the Sencha Forum but no avail.

We are using extJS 7.3.x classic. Thanks.

Edit: just an update, this seems to be a bug unique to Ext 7.3.x classic. Tried doing it in 6.2.x classic and it's working fine. Any insights on why it's happening to the newer version would be appreciated.